# Create a class that draws lines between points created by another class

Tags: javascript, function, class, p5.js

I'm making a program that animates bezier curves with p5.js. I've created this program already once but this time I'm refining it. (I'm basically copying Jason Davies work [here](https://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/)) I want to be able to create as many control points as I want for the curve. So far I have a class that creates a control point at a random point on my canvas whenever I press a button. This is how far I've gotten:

```
let controlPoints = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);

    //Adds a button called "Add controlpoint" that calls the function "addControlPoint"
    button = createButton('Add controlpoint');
    button.position(10, 10);
    button.mousePressed(addControlPoint);

    //Adds a button called "Remove controlpoint" that calls the function "removeControlPoint"
    button = createButton('Remove controlpoint');
    button.position(10, 45);
    button.mousePressed(removeControlPoint);
}

function draw() {
    background(55);

    //Draws all of the controlpoints in the array "controlPoints"
    for (let i = 0; i < controlPoints.length; i++) {
        controlPoints[i].show();
        controlPoints[i].overPoint();
    }
}

//If the button "Add controlpoint" is pressed create controlpoint att random location
function addControlPoint() {
    controlPoints.push(new controlPointBrain(random(width), random(height), 25));
}

//If the button "Remove controlpoint" is pressed remove latest controlpoint added
function removeControlPoint() {
    controlPoints.pop();
}
```

and this is my class for the control points

```
class controlPointBrain {
    constructor(x_, y_, r_) {
        this.x = x_;
        this.y = y_;
        this.r = r_;
    }

    overPoint() {
        //If the controlpoint is over the x-edge stop it from going over
        if (this.x >= width) {
            this.x = width-(this.r/2);
        } else if (this.x < 0) {
            this.x = 0+(this.r/2);
        }

        //If the controlpoint is over the y-edge stop it from going over
        if (this.y >= height) {
            this.y = height-(this.r/2);
        } else if (this.y < 0) {
            this.y = 0+(this.r/2);
        }
    }

    show() {
        strokeWeight(4);
        fill(55);

        //Checks if the mouse is over the controlpoint
        if (mouseX <= this.x+(this.r/2) && mouseX >= this.x-(this.r/2) &&
            mouseY >= this.y-(this.r/2) && mouseY <= this.y+(this.r/2))
        {
            stroke(55, 255, 50);
        } else {
            stroke(255, 50, 50);
        }

        //Draws an ellipse
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r);
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a class/function that draws a line between the latest control point and the one before it every time I add a control point. Is it possible to create a class that automatically draws these lines? Or should I create a function that does this?
Any helpful criticism on what I've already programmed would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> function that draws a line between the latest control point and the one before it every time I add a control point

That's only the last and next to last points? You can grab those from the end of the array and draw a line between them. You could do that in the draw loop after you iterate over the points.

```
if ( controlPoints.length > 1 ){
    let lastPoint = controlPoints[ controlPoints.length - 1 ];
    let secondToLastPoint = controlPoints[ controlPoints.length - 2 ];

    //draw line between this point and otherPoint
    line( lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, secondToLastPoint.x, secondToLastPoint.y );
}
```

The code is very neat, looks good. The only thing I would do different is calling `controlPoints[i].overPoint();` every frame. I assume this exists because you are going to have the points moveable? I would only call that function after I actually moved a point.

Comment: This works great, thanks! Yes, I'm going to make the point moveable.